# How do I get "RAM buffer" value when running cat /proc/iomem?

Tags: kernel, ram

When I use CentOS with cat /proc/iomem command , it will display RAM buffer this item , but when I use Ubuntu it didn't show it.

Does it have any command or replace method can show this information for Ubuntu ?

Here is the CentOS info about RAM buffer down below.

```
  3ca400000-3cab92120 : Kernel code
  3cab92121-3cb1902bf : Kernel data
  3cb3b2000-3cb688fff : Kernel bss
  437000000-437ffffff : RAM buffer <-- this one
```

But When I use Ubuntu , it did't show.

```
sudo cat /proc/iomem
00000000-00000fff : Reserved
00001000-0009ffff : System RAM
000a0000-000fffff : Reserved
000a0000-000bffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
000f0000-000fffff : System ROM
00100000-7927cfff : System RAM
2d200000-2dc031d0 : Kernel code
2dc031d1-2e42e57f : Kernel data
2e964000-2ec4efff : Kernel bss
7927d000-79407fff : Reserved
```

Comment: It works for me. Ubuntu 20.04.4 server with kernel 5.13.0-52-generic. `sudo cat /proc/iomem | grep "RAM buffer"` gave `86e800000-86fffffff : RAM buffer`.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.14, but it didn't show this item.I still try now, thanks for your comment.

Comment: I started an old 16.04 server VM, kernel 4..4.0-210, and confirm the lack of "RAM buffer" output with that old kernel.

Comment: My system is Ubuntu 16.04 server . So ,do you know this problem is about kernel version or Ubuntu version ?

Comment: Kernel version.

Comment: @DougSmythies OK, Thanks for your help !

Comment: I found the RAM buffer physical memory address ! 
In this case , System RAM on the top of all kernel item is the range of RAM buffer.
 ` **00100000-7927cfff : System RAM** `
So,this item is which I need to use.